# How to create a *.crt file out of keystore? (SSL / Tomcat)

Tags: ssl, tomcat

to use https (ssl) with tomcat i build a keystore with this commands:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias [youralias] -keyalg RSA -keystore [/preferred/keystore/path]

$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias [youralias] -file [yourcertificatname].csr -keystore [path/to/your/keystore]
```

Now i want to import a certificate into InternetExplorer (Menü->Internet Options->Content->Certificate-Import). The import function of the IE requires an *.crt file. So how can i create a *.crt file out of the keystore. I was looking aroung on the net to get some infos. I only found infos to create *.jks file or import *.crt to the keystore. But not erxport or create a *.crt out of the keystore.

Thx and kind regards
yefpie

Comment: I'm on mobile but use the `-export` and the `-rfc` options to get the base64 printable encoding format I.E. expects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OpenSSL for this, Tomcat keystore is a .p12 keystore type:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497719/extract-public-private-key-from-pkcs12-file-for-later-use-in-ssh-pk-authentifica